# How to define a \dotfill macro with a minimum width?

Tags: fill

I want to define the `\entry` macro to make a list of references.

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\def\entry#1#2#3{\textbf{#1}~#2\dotfill#3\par}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\entry{1}{aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  a a a a}{48}
\entry{2}{bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  b b b
  b}{48, 56, 78}

\entry{3}{aaaa bbb ddd  eeeeee cc cc ccc cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  c c c
  c}{123}

\entry{4}{aaaa bbb dddd  eeeeeeeee cc cc ccc cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  c c c
  c}{123}

\entry{5}{aaaaaaa bbb ddd  eeeeeeee cc cc ccc cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  c c c
  c}{123}

\entry{6}{aaaaaaa bbb ddd  eeeeeeee cc cc ccc cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc c
  cccc\\\null}{123}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The entries 1, 2, and 3 are ok. But the entries 4, and 5 should be like the 6th entry.

By what macro replace `\dotfill` to automatically get entry 6 instead of entries 4 and 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has a minimum width of 2em, but customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mdotfill}[1][2em]{%
  \leavevmode
  \linebreak[0]%
  \mbox{}\nobreak
  \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hskip #1 plus 1fill
  \kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\entry}[3]{\textbf{#1}~#2\mdotfill#3\par}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\entry{1}{aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  a a a a}{48}
\entry{2}{bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  b b b
  b}{48, 56, 78}

\entry{3}{aaaa bbb ddd  eeeeee cc cc ccc cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  c c c
  c}{123}

\entry{4}{aaaa bbb dddd  eeeeeeeee cc cc ccc cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  c c c
  c}{123}

\entry{5}{aaaaaaa bbb ddd  eeeeeeee cc cc ccc cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  c c c
  c}{123}

\entry{6}{aaaaaaa bbb ddd  eeeeeeee cc cc ccc cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc  cc c
  cccc\\\null}{123}

\end{document}
```

[image]